# joda-time ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime() misbehaving

Tags: java, datetime, parsing, jodatime, datetime-format

[ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime()](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTimeParser--) is supposed to be lenient and flexible. E.g. millis are optional, date is optional, timezone is optional, timezone can be `Z` or `+/- HH[:MM]`

But it's not. What am I missing?

Using version `joda-time:2.9.9` (also tried `2.10.8` with same result)

```
import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Arrays.asList("2020-11-22T01:59:59.001+00:00", "2020-11-22T01:59:59.001Z", "2020-11-22T01:59:59+00:00",
        "2020-11-22T01:59:59Z", "01:59:59").forEach(s -> {
        try {
            System.out.println(String.format("%-30s -- %s", s, ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().parseDateTime(s)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%-30s -- %s", s, e.getMessage()));
        }
    });
}
```

Output:

```
2020-11-22T01:59:59.001+00:00  -- 2020-11-22T01:59:59.001Z
2020-11-22T01:59:59.001Z       -- 2020-11-22T01:59:59.001Z
2020-11-22T01:59:59+00:00      -- Invalid format: "2020-11-22T01:59:59+00:00" is malformed at "+00:00"
2020-11-22T01:59:59Z           -- Invalid format: "2020-11-22T01:59:59Z" is malformed at "Z"
01:59:59.000                   -- Invalid format: "01:59:59.000" is malformed at ":59:59.000"
```

[javadoc](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTimeParser--):

```
public static DateTimeFormatter dateTimeParser()

Returns a generic ISO datetime parser which parses either a date or a time or both.

The returned formatter can only be used for parsing, printing is unsupported.

The parser is strict by default, thus time string 24:00 cannot be parsed.

It accepts formats described by the following syntax:

 datetime          = time | date-opt-time
 time              = 'T' time-element [offset]
 date-opt-time     = date-element ['T' [time-element] [offset]]
 date-element      = std-date-element | ord-date-element | week-date-element
 std-date-element  = yyyy ['-' MM ['-' dd]]
 ord-date-element  = yyyy ['-' DDD]
 week-date-element = xxxx '-W' ww ['-' e]
 time-element      = HH [minute-element] | [fraction]
 minute-element    = ':' mm [second-element] | [fraction]
 second-element    = ':' ss [fraction]
 fraction          = ('.' | ',') digit+
 offset            = 'Z' | (('+' | '-') HH [':' mm [':' ss [('.' | ',') SSS]]])
```

Comment: You're linking to the docs for `dateTimeParser` but invoking `dateTime()`.

Comment: What java version are you using? If it is 8 or above, then the [joda home page](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/index.html) instructs you to _migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project_

Comment: @jensgram, yes, that was the problem! `(－‸ლ)`

Comment: @Abra, all predefined [formats in DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) seem to be `STRICT`. Is there some simple way to get a SMART parser like `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser()`?

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.SMART)`? It’s not an exact equivalent to the Joda-Time thing, but it should be SMART.

Comment: As I read the format description that you quote, a time only string should have a `T` prefix, so should not parse `01:59:59.000` without `T`.

Comment: @OleV.V. I think the javadoc for SMART style said it can make allowed value ranges flexible, not make parts optional.

Comment: That’s my understanding too.

Comment: Which offset do you want if there is no offset in the string?

Comment: @OleV.V. default UTC, preferably configurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### java.time

As Abra suggested in a comment, you may want to follow the official Joda-Time recommendation and move on to java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

The following will not give you the full flexibility of the Joda-Time parser, but it does parse your five example strings. And you may be able to adapt it further to any further needs you may have.

```
    ZoneOffset defaultOffset = ZoneOffset.UTC; // Configurable
    LocalDate defaultDate = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    
    DateTimeFormatter flexibleFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .optionalStart()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            .appendLiteral('T')
            .optionalEnd()
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, defaultDate.getYear())
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, defaultDate.getMonthValue())
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, defaultDate.getDayOfMonth())
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendOffsetId()
            .optionalEnd()
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, defaultOffset.getTotalSeconds())
            .toFormatter();

    Arrays.asList("2020-11-22T01:59:59.001+00:00", "2020-11-22T01:59:59.001Z", "2020-11-22T01:59:59+00:00",
            "2020-11-22T01:59:59Z", "01:59:59").forEach(s -> {
            try {
                System.out.println(String.format("%-30s -- %s", s, OffsetDateTime.parse(s, flexibleFormatter)));
            } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
                System.out.println(String.format("%-30s -- %s", s, dtpe.getMessage()));
            }
        });
```

Output when I ran just now in Europe/Copenhagen time zone:

> ```
> 2020-11-22T01:59:59.001+00:00  -- 2020-11-22T01:59:59.001Z
> 2020-11-22T01:59:59.001Z       -- 2020-11-22T01:59:59.001Z
> 2020-11-22T01:59:59+00:00      -- 2020-11-22T01:59:59Z
> 2020-11-22T01:59:59Z           -- 2020-11-22T01:59:59Z
> 01:59:59                       -- 2020-11-19T01:59:59Z
> ```

From the Joda-Time home page:

> Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project.
> No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate
> to `java.time` (JSR-310).

### What went wrong in your code?

jensgram said it already in the comment:

> You're linking to the docs for `dateTimeParser` but invoking
> `dateTime()`

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Joda-Time — Home](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to stick with joda for now. But hopefully this will help someone else.